# Azure Data Factory Connector for crunchbase

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can someone let me know if there is a Azure Data Factory connector for Crunchbase?

Crunchbase is a leader in private-company data.

Alternatively, can someone let me know if its possible to connect to Crunchbase via REST in Data Factory

Comment: list of connectors given at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores, But unfortunately it does not have connector for Crunchbase.

Comment: As a workaround If it provides RESTful APIs, you can use generic REST connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked list of connectors given here [Supported data stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores), But unfortunately it does not have connector for Crunchbase.

If you need to move data to/from a data store that is not in the service built-in connector list, here are some extensible options:

For database and data warehouse, usually you can find a corresponding ODBC driver, with which you can use generic ODBC connector.

**For SaaS applications:**

If it provides RESTful APIs, you can use generic REST connector.

If it has OData feed, you can use generic OData connector.

If it provides SOAP APIs, you can use generic HTTP connector.

If it has ODBC driver, you can use generic ODBC connector.

For others, check if you can load data to or expose data as any supported data stores, e.g. Azure Blob/File/FTP/SFTP/etc, then let the service pick up from there. You can invoke custom data loading mechanism via Azure Function, Custom activity, Databricks/HDInsight, Web activity, etc.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview